# Where can I find the events produced when editing an ui-grid cell?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Here http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable you read that those events happens: BEGIN_CELL_EDIT, CANCEL_CELL_EDIT and END_CELL_EDIT.

But nowhere I found how to handle the events. 
Just here (http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/309_editable_with_cellnav), casually, I found the following examples using the function afterCellEdit I suppose equals to the function handling the END_CELL_EDIT events

```
 $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
          //set gridApi on scope
          $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
          gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope,function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue){
            $scope.msg.lastCellEdited = 'edited row id:' + rowEntity.id + ' Column:' + colDef.name + ' newValue:' + newValue + ' oldValue:' + oldValue ;
            $scope.$apply();
          });
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer, in the API:
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/api/ui.grid.edit.api:PublicApi

Haven't removed the question because was not easy for me to find. May be useful for other ui-grid users.